# When I set the final variable to 4, how do I ensure that the top 4 lines are erased and not the bottom 4?

Tags: java

I am trying to print an hourglass figure. Initially, the LINE constant variable was set to 8 and it works fine. However, when I set LINE = 4; the bottom half looks good, but the upper half prints the top 4 lines instead of the bottom 4 lines (in order to match the bottom half of the hourglass.)

After setting the LINE variable to 4, I've tried to switch the first and third for loops to print the bottom 4 lines of the upper half of the hourglass. I've also done trial and error with the variables in each of the for loops, making some of the variables in the first for loop negative to try to print the 4 lines from the bottom. I've also used the debugger, and did not find any syntax or logic errors.

```
public static final int LINE = 4;

public static void question8(){
    System.out.println("+----------------+");

    // UPPER HALF (where the "error" occurs)
    for (int i=1; i<=LINE;i++){
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int j=1; j<i;j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("\\");
        for (int k=7; k>i-1;k--){//this was the line changed!
            System.out.print("..");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        for (int j=1;j<i; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    //BOTTOM HALF
    for (int i=1; i<=LINE;i++){ // i controls the #of lines
        System.out.print("|");
        for(int j=8; j>i;j--){ // j controls the # of spaces before / in every line.
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        for (int k=0; k<i-1;k++){ // k is to control how many dots we have in every line.
            System.out.print("..");
        }
        System.out.print("\\");
        for (int j=8;j>i;j--){ // j is to control how many spaces we have after \ in every line.
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("|");
    }
    System.out.println("+----------------+");
}
```

expected results:

```
+--------+
|\....../|
| \..../ |
|  \../  |
|   \/   |
|   /\   |
|  /..\  |
| /....\ |
|/......\|
+--------+
```

actual results:

```
+----------------+
|\............../|
| \............/ |
|  \........../  |
|   \......../   |
|       /\       |
|      /..\      |
|     /....\     |
|    /......\    |
+----------------+

no error messages
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some hard coded stuff specific to LINE 8 in your code, update your code as below and it will be dynamic for all number values. (But you would need to change `+----------------+"` accordingly.)

```
public static final int LINE = 4;
    public static void question8() {
        System.out.println("+----------------+");

        // UPPER HALF (where the "error" occurs)
        for (int i = 1; i <= LINE; i++) {
          System.out.print("|");
          for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          System.out.print("\\");
          for (int k = LINE - 1; k > i - 1; k--) {//this was the line changed!
            System.out.print("..");
          }
          System.out.print("/");
          for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          System.out.println("|");
        }
        //BOTTOM HALF
        for (int i = 1; i <= LINE; i++) { // i controls the #of lines
          System.out.print("|");
          for (int j = LINE; j > i; j--) { // j controls the # of spaces before / in every line.
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          System.out.print("/");
          for (int k = 0; k < i - 1; k++) { // k is to control how many dots we have in every line.
            System.out.print("..");
          }
          System.out.print("\\");
          for (int j = LINE; j > i; j--) { // j is to control how many spaces we have after \ in every line.
            System.out.print(" ");
          }
          System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println("+----------------+");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. There are three for loops that you have to change the starting values of,

```
// Top half
for (int k=7; k>i-1;k--){//this was the line changed!
    System.out.print("..");
}
...
// Bottom half
for(int j=8; j>i;j--){ // j controls the # of spaces before / in every line.
    System.out.print(" ");
}
...
for (int j=8;j>i;j--){ // j is to control how many spaces we have after \ in every line.
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

In the first for loop, `k` should start out equal to `LINE - 1`. And in the next two for loops, `j` should be initialized equal to `LINE`. This way, the function fully depends on the value `LINE` instead of some hardcoded value. However, you will still have to change the following print statements at the top and bottom of your function,

```
System.out.println("+----------------+");
```

to print only a certain amount of dashes based on the `LINE` variable.